# Can't rename file using mv

Tags: mv

Am trying a published solution to remove `systemd-shim` error after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 but get a bash syntax error as follows (you can see I tried different permutations of the same command in terminal).

[image: screenshot of script error]

I don't understand why it results in this error.

Comment: `<original file name>` and `<new file name>` are only place holders for real file names you should exchange them with real file names, could you post which instruction you are following?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I guess you are following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/838673/264781) instruction.

As I said in comments, `<original file name>` and `<new file name>` are only place holders for real file names and you should exchange them with those names.

So the real command is:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.bk
```

which you can simplify to:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service{,.bk}
```

Answer (score 4):

You get this error message because `<` is used for [redirection](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).  If you quote the arguments to `mv` with single quotes you get a clearer error message:

```
$ mv  '<original file name>' '<new file name>'
mv: cannot stat ‘<original file name>’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Thanj you so much for clarifying this for me. I have managed to solve the systemd-shim problem! : O )